# How to create SQL Server add-in?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-addin

i try to develop an add-in for SQL Server Management Studio like this:

http://aspalliance.com/1374_Extend_Functionality_in_SQL_Server_2005_Management_Studio_with_Addins.all

But: I've searched in google about SSMS add-ins. I've found a link which is great but I can not find it today:( May be you can give some best advise and link :(

Some author said that

*Things might change with SQL 2008 or it might remain the same. The assemblies might change a little bit and there will be some support provided by Microsoft for the add-ins. There are various daily tasks that you can automate or provide a better way then what is provided by SSMS. You just need to visualize your tool and keep on looking for ways to code it and implement it.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx

I'm feeling lucky :)